# Anomaly Detection Techniques

Tags: anomaly-detection, anomaly

Often the hardest part of solving an Anomaly Detection problem can be finding the right technique for the job.

Different Anomaly techniques are better suited for different types of data and different problems.

Are there any flowchart/tree diagrams that are designed to give users a bit of a rough guide on different anomaly techniques and the approach problems with regard to which technique to try on the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anomaly Detection Techniques](https://coggle.it/diagram/Wc0BdWjgVAAB4HHn/t/anomaly-detection-techniques)

[image]

[Here](https://coggle.it/diagram/Wc0BdWjgVAAB4HHn/t/anomaly-detection-techniques) is a link  from coggle that has different Anomaly Detection Techniques